# Positive format of the word 'weird'?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What is the equivalent adjective of the word **different**?

It must give a positive feeling and must be opposite to the negative feeling word **'weird'**.

I'm writing some dialogs for my short-film where this word is so important.

More than one word suggestions are welcome and thank you all in advance.

Comment: *differing* seems neutral in tone. And if you were from [Austin, TX](http://www.keepaustinweird.com/home.html) you'd know **weird** is one of the most positive words there is for *different*.  But you could settle for **odd** and then use a, um, thesaurus...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Unique*** is usually used for being different in a good way.

Comment: I really think most these adjectives are gonna be neutral and the noun give the positive or negative vibe. Hitler was unique.

Comment: Unique is unique among other adjectives.

Comment: Are you saying unique is most unique? ;)

Comment: @CarSmack: That could be a pleonasm if we considered the core meaning of _unique_. But, _unique_ has developed a less precise meaning in 19th century: "very remarkable, special, or unusual". So we can most certainly say it is the most unique adjective :)

Comment: What about "special"? I'm really curious about that.

Comment: I saw a vanity license plate a while ago: "UNIQUE6".  "UNIQUE" was not unique.

Answer (score 2):

You asked for more than one suggestion, so here are some that spring to mind that have a less negative feeling than 'weird'. I am not sure if you are using it to describe a person, but they could also fit other things

From [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/quirky)

> **Quirky**: Having or characterized by peculiar or unexpected traits or aspects

Things are often described as quirky when they are unusual or different, but also interesting and unusual.

From [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/kooky)

> **Kooky**: (especially of a person) strange in their appearance or behaviour, especially in a way that is interesting:

I think this is a 'cute' way of describing someones unusual habits or demeanour, in an endearing way.

From [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/offbeat)

> **Offbeat** > unusual, unconventional, or eccentric

To describe someone, or something, as offbeat gives the impression of them not running with the herd but being individual and confident in being so.

It really depends on the context and what you are describing as to whether these suggestions  are suitable.

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot. But I had to choose the answer with **unique**, because it was the word which I was searching for.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I don't associate the adjective *weird* with negative feeling.

If you are afraid that people may mistake a description you have written for a derogatory remark, try to be more descriptive in your writing. Don't just use an adjective to describe a person or thing (e.g. "He is weird").

Here is an example: if you are describing a person who thinks differently and thus are considered "weird" among people around her or him, this is what you can  write.

> She/he has a unconventional way of thinking.

Another example: rather than calling someone who sees life in a very unconventional way weird, you can say

> She/he has a unorthodox view of life.